# Multiple values to pivot in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset where I would like to pivot the entire dataframe, using certain columns as values.

Data

```
id  date    sun moon    stars   total   pcp base    final   status  space   galaxy
aa  Q1 21   5   1       2       8       0   200     41      5       1       1
aa  Q2 21   4   1       2       7       1   200     50      6       2       1
```

Desired

```
id  date    type    pcp base    final   final2  status  type2   final3
aa  Q1 21   sun     0   200     41      5       5       space   1
aa  Q1 21   moon    0   200     41      1       5       galaxy  1
aa  Q1 21   stars   0   200     41      2       5       space   1
aa  Q2 21   sun     1   200     50      4       6       space   2
aa  Q2 21   moon    1   200     50      1       6       galaxy  1
aa  Q2 21   stars   1   200     50      2       6       space   2
```

Doing

```
df.drop(columns='total').melt(['id','date','final','final2','base','ppp'],var_name='type',value_name='ppp')
```

This works well in pivoting the first set of values (sun, moon etc) however, not sure how to incorporate the second 'set'  space and galaxy.
Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51519101/simultaneously-melt-multiple-columns-in-python-pandas)

Comment: How the `final3` column is set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a partial answer:

```
cols = ['id', 'date', 'pcp', 'base', 'final', 'status']

df = df.drop(columns='total')

df1 = df.melt(id_vars=cols, value_vars=['sun', 'moon', 'stars'], var_name='type')
df2 = df.melt(id_vars=cols, value_vars=['galaxy', 'space'], var_name='type2')

out = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=cols)
```

At this point, your dataframe looks like:

```
>>> out
    id   date  pcp  base  final  status   type  value_x   type2  value_y
0   aa  Q1 21    0   200     41       5    sun        5  galaxy        1
1   aa  Q1 21    0   200     41       5    sun        5   space        1
2   aa  Q1 21    0   200     41       5   moon        1  galaxy        1
3   aa  Q1 21    0   200     41       5   moon        1   space        1
4   aa  Q1 21    0   200     41       5  stars        2  galaxy        1
5   aa  Q1 21    0   200     41       5  stars        2   space        1
6   aa  Q2 21    1   200     50       6    sun        4  galaxy        1
7   aa  Q2 21    1   200     50       6    sun        4   space        2
8   aa  Q2 21    1   200     50       6   moon        1  galaxy        1
9   aa  Q2 21    1   200     50       6   moon        1   space        2
10  aa  Q2 21    1   200     50       6  stars        2  galaxy        1
11  aa  Q2 21    1   200     50       6  stars        2   space        2
```

Now the question is how `total3` is set to reduce the dataframe?